# Question about void functions and call by value

Tags: c++, void

I'm a newbie who has been in c++ for two days.

Can I define more than one void function like I wrote?
Where should I modify to implement the above?

Before calling callbyvalue: 1, 2
After calling callbyvalue: 1, 2
Before calling swap: 3, 4
After calling swap: 4, 3

````
void Exchange1(int a, int b)
{
    int temp1;

    temp1 = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp1;
}

void Exchange2(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp2;

    temp2 = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp2;

int main()
{
    int a, b, x, y;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    x = 3;
    y = 4;

    printf("Call-by-value before : %d , %d\n", a, b);
    
    Exchange1(a, b);

    printf("Call-by-value after : %d , %d\n", a, b);

    printf("swap before : %d %d\n", x, y);

    Exchange2(&x, &y);

    printf("swap after : %d %d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: I'm sorry, what is exactly your question ? I fail to understand what is puzzling you

Comment: it is not clear what your question is exactly. Of course you can define more than one function. You just did that. "Where should I modify to implement the above?" what is "the above" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to implement something like
Call-by-value before : 1,2 
Call-by-value after : 1,2 
swap before : 3,4 
swap after : 4,3
where can i edit?

Comment: @trialNerror
I want to implement something like
Call-by-value before : 1,2 
Call-by-value after : 1,2 
swap before : 3,4 
swap after : 4,3
where can i edit?

Comment: `Exchange1` is working on local variables. What it does to `a` and `b` inside the function will not be visible when the function returns. You probably mean to do `void Exchange1(int& a, int& b)` which takes `a` and `b` by reference.

Comment: I guess you haven't already been introduced to [references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references) am I right?

Comment: "I want to implement something like ..." isnt that what your code does already? `Exchange1` doesnt exchange anything and `Exchange2` does swap the values. Thats what you have in your expected output and I think thats what the code does

Comment: do you want to "fix" `Exchange1` such that it actually does swap the values of its parameters?

Comment: This looks like C to me. What kind of C++ learning material you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define more than one void function, actually unlimited void function you can write if you want.

Please check your `void Exchange2(int* x, int* y)` function.

Closing bracket is missing here.

```
void Exchange2(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp2;

    temp2 = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp2;

int main()
```

After added the closing bracket, i got this result.

[image]

Now my question is, are you looking for this answer ?